# Do I need to copy static objects if I want to access them from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a project that uses `AsyncTask` to get work done in background.
This project also uses a class as a generic holder for static values like database keys, but also for one or two useful objects for the whole project. Let's say this class is called `public class Constants`.

I want to access one of these objects from an `AsyncTask`, and I don't know if I need to copy it or not.
I am not actually getting errors or crashes, but I get some user feedback reporting crashes that I cannot reproduce, so I'm gessing I am doing something wrong with this.

My current processing is this:

```
onStart() {// somewhere in the UI thread  
new MyTask(Constants.theObject).execute(); // (1)  
}  
// ...  
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...> {  
MyObjectType object;  
MyTask(MyObjectType theObjectInstance) {  
object = theObjectInstance; // (2)  
// ...  
doInBackground() { // (3)  
//  ...  
}
```

In `(1)`, `Constants.theObject` is a static object created at application startup

In `(2)`, I get a reference to the existing static object `Constants.theObject`

In `(3)`, we are no longer in the UI thread, and I want to access `Constants.theObject` (which may also be being used in the main thread)

.

I think there are three possible cases.

- this code is ugly, I should do otherwise
- this code is OK, the user feedback is not about this
- this code is quite OK, but I should make a copy of `Constants.theObject` if I want to use it in `doInBackground`; otherwise it can fail

I hope you can help me! Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean when you write "static object" as there's really no such concept in Java. There are static variables, and they can refer to objects... but the object itself isn't static.

Comment: The Constants class is as this: 

public class Constants {  
...  
private static MyObjectType myObject;  
public static getMyObject() {  
if (myObject == null) {  
myObject = new MyObjectType();  
}  
return myObject;  
}

Comment: What leads you to believe the crash is because of this as opposed to any one of a dozen other things that could cause crashes? Can you at least get a logcat report from a user who's reported an app crash? There's nothing inherently problematic with using static variables, but what are you keeping statically? If you're keeping references to Views or Activities, you could be causing all sorts of accidental mischief, but it's far more likely you're running into one of many other AsyncTask issues where a background task's invoking activity dies due to a screen rotation or the like.

Comment: Hi Yoni, thanks for your reply. I don't have a logcat but I have a stack trace: http://pastebin.com/6iL4JJkX   ChercheStationsTask is the AsyncTask, the line 250 uses Constants.theObject.something(). The static object is an object containing a List<Service> that are used for plugin management in my application.

Comment: And the thing that leads me to think the crash is because of this is my previous experience in C++ of multithreading programming. I have here a UI thread and a background thread which try to access the same resouce, I'm wondering if the multithreading can cause Constants.theObject to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've written, I don't think you need to make a copy, unless `MyObjectType` is NOT thread-safe, in which case, you need to ensure that only 1 thread at a time is modifying it/it's-non-thread-safe-methods. (Making a copy would indeed solve this, but if you can make a copy, is a global-static really what you should be using anyway?)

Are you 100% sure that 1 and 3 can only happen AFTER the object has been initialized?

Comment: OK you pointed out something that I should have thought of before asking, maybe. I will double-check if MyObjectType is or is not thread-safe. And I have changed the way it is accessed from Constants, with a method creating the object if it is null, instead of directly accessing the object.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because more than one thread is trying to change the same object. it may cause unexpected results/complete failure. You may wanna use some lock so that no 2 threads can updates the object at the same time. This case it will slow down your asynch operations as they all depend on exact one intance. I guess you are using static object for a reason, you may want to consider it doing some other way if possible.

Comment: I think also too, but I was wondering, as I am no Java/android expert, if there were not some kind of magical automatic critical sections management...

Comment: There is the synchronized method/block.
If you're looking for something more abstract, there's many useful classes in the java.util.concurrent package, and it's two subpackages java.util.concurrent 
java.util.concurrent.atomic 
java.util.concurrent.locks